# Loop function in python

Tags: python, loops, printing, echo

Could any one tell me whats wrong in the following code? (In Python 2.7)

```
def echo(msg):
    print msg


def loop(x,y):
    a = 0
    while (a < x + 1):
        a = a + 1
        y

loop(5,echo("ok"))
```

I should be getting "ok" five times, but instead I just get "ok" once, no matter what 
amount I set x to be.

Comment: `echo("ok")` prints *right then* and evaluate to `None`. Add `print a` above `y` and add `print "start"` above `while` to see what I mean. If you want to defer evaluation pass in a function or lambda (and then invoke it with `()`) ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

echo("ok") is being evaluated before passing it to the function maybe, this is what you really want

```
def loop(x,y, *args):
    a = 0
    while (a < x + 1):
            a = a + 1
            y(*args)

def echo(msg):
     print msg

loop(5,echo, "ok")
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're evaluating `echo("ok")` when you call `loop`.

What you probably want to do is call `echo("ok")` on each iteration.

```
def echo(msg):
    print msg

def call_echo_ok():
    echo("ok")       

def loop(x,y):
    a = 0
    while (a < x + 1):
        a = a + 1
        y()

loop(5, call_echo_ok)
```

Note that this can be done more concisely with lambda functions.

```
def echo(msg):
    print msg   

def loop(x,y):
    a = 0
    while (a < x + 1):
        a = a + 1
        y()

loop(5, lambda: echo('ok'))
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try this:

```
def loop(times,message):
     for i in range(times):
          print message

loop(5,"Ok")
```

Comment: Is there any way to keep what function is being looped variable so that I can use the same "loop" function for everything I need to loop?

Comment: Well, I meant more like Moshe's/JoseP's solutions, in being able to not only use the "echo" function, but loop any function i chose. Thanks for the help though...